# Strange behaviour adding HashMap to TreeSet

Tags: java, dictionary, set

I have the following problem adding a `HashMap<String,String>` to a `TreeSet<HashMap<String,String>>`. The code is as follows:

```
... Do something
XMLRoot root = XMLRoot
.newBuild()
.setTrx(
    Tag
    .newBuild()
    .setName("trx")
    .addAttribute("type", "04/01")
    .addAttribute("id", id));
... => BreakPoint here!
```

Now what the method `addAttribute()` does is:

```
public Tag addAttribute(String name, String value) {
    // Create the attribute.
    HashMap<String, String> att = new HashMap<String, String>();
    att.put(name, value);

    attributes.add(att);
    return this;
}
```

The `attributes` variable is a collection of type `TreeSet<HashMap<String,String>>`. Now using Netbeans debugger I've added a BreakPoint right after the creation of the XMLRoot object, and what I've found is that it never reaches the breakpoint. The problem is that no exceptions are thrown, no errors, nothing. Another strange thing is that if I add only one element using the `addAttribute()` method then all works fine.

**Question:** What could have caused the execution to terminate inside the add() method of the TreeSet class for the second element...?

**Note:** Using the debugger I managed to see the first attribute being set, but I never reach the second one, which means the execution ends abruptly while adding the second element.

**Details:** Apple JDK 1.6.0_51 64-Bit OSX 10.8.4 (Mountain Lion)

Comment: When you say it never reaches the breakpoint, where _does_ it continue?  Does the JVM terminate at that point?  Are you sure you're not swallowing an exception somewhere?  Oh, and BTW, using a mutable object as a value in a set is likely to cause problems if the value ever changes.

Comment: The JVM does not end, but the BreakPoint isn't reached. Also code after that never gets executed also.
About swallowing an exception... Not that I know of.
Also the thread does not end, because I execute this statement from the EDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost certainly getting a `ClassCastException`, because elements of `TreeSet` must implement `Comparable` and `HashMap` doesn't. To be honest, I'm surprised the compiler allows this; I thought `TreeSet` would be more explicit in its parameterization.

Your say that you're running this on the event dispatch thread. The EDT has an uncaught exception handler that normally prints exceptions on StdErr but otherwise ignores them. It's possible, if you're not seeing a message, that this handler has been replaced by your application.